# php mysql query with hyphen character

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query problem with hyphen character.

```
$user = "test-user";
$q = @mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE user='$user'");
echo mysql_error(); //no error message
```

test-user record is in table but query result coming empty. Also mysql error message is empty. What is wrong?

---

EDIT:
Thank you for answers. I apologize to everyone. I found the problem and I see now the problem is not in the query. Problem coming form regex.

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i", $user)) //dash character not in regex
{
$q = @mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE user='$user'");
}
```

I've corrected the problem as follows:

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i", $user)) //added \- to regex for dash
{
$q = @mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE user='$user'");
}
```

Comment: For one thing - don't use `@` to suppress the error message from `mysql_query`; for another - you should look at using mysqli_* instead, as the mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Comment: Give your table with sample date, that is not working. The error is very minor - it has nothing to do with hyphen.

Comment: It may just be your example, but 'table' is a reserved word in MySQL and thus needs to be back-ticked. But you should be back ticking all table and columns names by course of habit.

Comment: `$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM \`table\` WHERE user='".$user."'") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to escape the data string.

```
$user = "test-user";
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$q = @mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE user='$user'");
echo mysql_error(); //no error message
```

But I would also recommend using `or die()` syntax instead of the `@mysql_query` you have in place.

```
$user = "test-user";
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE user='$user'") or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: And note that the mysql_ suite of functions are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Any difference if you change the **query** to:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE user='".$user."'");
```

Unless I'm having a very slow Sunday I think you're searching for the literal string `$user` rather than the `variable value`.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference - the string is wrapped in double quotes, so `$user` will be substituted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$user = "test-user";
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE user='".$user."'")
    or die(mysql_error());//no error message;
```

Full example with mysqli_:

```
    $host = "";
    $user = "";
    $password = "";
    $database = "";   

    $user_name_query = "test-user"; // If this value is from a form please read more about sql-injection. 

    // open connection to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           // SELECT QUERY
           $query = "SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE user='".$user_name_query."'";
         mysqli_query($link,$query)  or die("Query failed");

        }
// close connection to database
        mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: A post on sql-injection can be found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php.

Comment: @webmaster you could change the `=` into `LIKE` and then use wild cards for the text search.

Answer (score 0):

```
       $p = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE user='$user'");
        if (!$p) 
        {
            die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {
            echo mysql_result($p>0);
        }
```

try it